# How do I use Bash in VirtualBox?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, virtualbox, iso-image

Just started using VirtualBox. I have an ubuntu iso image on my usb that I can boot from. I ran ubuntu in VirtualBox in Window7 with no problem. How can I go about using Bash with Linux in VirtualBox?

Answer (score 3):

It works exactly the same way as using bash on Ubuntu outside of VirtualBox. You just launch a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> should work).

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, then type `xterm` end press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The `xterm` program is a terminal emulator for the X Window System.